# Loading images in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So here's the problem,

I'm trying to load images using jQuery to speed up the page downloading. 
To accomplish it, I have the following code as an image, which I want to load after the page loads.

```
<img src="/pixel.png" new-img="/newimage.png"/>
```

Then, to load the final image after the document fully loads, I've used the following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("img").attr("src", $("img").attr("new-img"));
});
```

This works fine for a single image, except I have multiple images that I want to convert to this.
I'm completely stumped as when I try and load multiple images like this, it sets all the images to the last image loaded.

I'm not sure, but does '$(this)' have anything to do with it?

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/AeroMcDoom/8sxED/

Comment: Are you sure you are not [reinventing the wheel](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+lazy+image+load)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use that:

```
$("img").attr("src", function(){return $(this).attr("new-img")});
```

FYI, you should use data-* attribute instead:

```
<img src="/pixel.png" data-img="/newimage.png"/>
```

And then:

```
 $("img").attr("src", function(){return $(this).data("img")});
```

Comment: What? you can use a function as the second parameter in attr()? Game changer!

Comment: @CerylWiltink Ya, check DOC: `.attr( attributeName, function(index, attr) )` http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("img").each(function(){$(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("new-img"))});
```

`.attr` on a selector that matches more than one element won't work as you do it. `.attr()` will set the attribute of all images its find to the defined content. Also you can't set it using `$("img").attr("new-img")` because `.attr(`) always returns only the first value it finds from the selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("img").each(function(){
      $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr("new-img"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little less overhead:

```
$(function(){ 
    $("img").each(function(){
        this.src = this.getAttribute('data-newimg');
    });
});
```

There is no need to initialize jQuery one or two times per image for this, unless you need this to work on IE6.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can save an extra HTTP request by doing this:

```
<div class="lazy">
  <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAA ///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
    data-src="/newimage.png"
    alt="Good to go" />
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {

   $(".lazy > img").each(function(){
      var src = $(this).attr('data-src');

      $(this).attr('src',src);
   });
});
```